# How to summarize data based on value of adjacent cell in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a dataframe called siteData with about 40,000 rows and 4 columns, here is an example.

```
Uniprot.ID Site Other_Sites
Q8NE71     E403     
Q8NE71     E705     
Q09666     E545     
Q09666     E550     
Q09666     E574     
Q09666     E766     
Q09666     E796
```

For a given `Uniprot.ID` I want to add all the sites listed to the `Other_Sites` column except for the one listed in the adjacent `Site` column.

I have already tried this simple for loop. I understand how to access the row number where a given `Uniprot.ID` occurs using `grepl`, what I'm having trouble with is writing the code in a way that it'll do this repeatedly for the whole data set.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(siteData)) {
  siteData$Other_Sites[i] = siteData[which(grepl(siteData$Uniprot.ID[i], 
                             siteData$Uniprot.ID)),2]
}
```

At the moment my code only adds one `Site` value to the `Other_Sites` column but for my example data I'd like it to look like this:

```
Uniprot.ID Site  Other_Sites
Q8NE71     E403    E705 
Q8NE71     E705    E403 
Q09666     E545    E550,E574,E766,E769  
Q09666     E550    E545,E574,E766,E769
Q09666     E574    E545,E550,E766,E769  
Q09666     E766    E545,E550,E574,E769  
Q09666     E796    E545,E550,E574,E766
```

More data put form:

```
structure(list(Uniprot.ID = c("Q8NE71", "Q8NE71", "Q8NE71", "Q8NE71", 
"Q8NE71", "Q8NE71", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", 
"Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", 
"Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", 
"Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q6P6C2", "E9PB61", "E9PB61"), 
    Site = c("E168", "E282", "E291", "E300", "E403", "E705", 
    "E545", "E550", "E574", "E766", "E796", "E797", "E924", "E1045", 
    "D1169", "E1173", "E1301", "E1422", "E4894", "E5219", "E5458", 
    "E5673", "E5689", "E5702", "E5703", "E5734", "E5755", "E5759", 
    "E50", "E249", "E250"), PMID = c(27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 
    27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 
    27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 
    27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 
    27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 
    27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L, 27256882L), Other_Sites = c("E20", 
    "E20", "E20", "E20", "E20", "E20", "E545", "E545", "E545", 
    "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", 
    "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", "E545", 
    "E545", "E545", "E545", "E50", "E249", "E249")), row.names = 100:130, class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `summarise` *Site* and paste them together for each group and then join two tables to get the desired output.

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Uniprot.ID) %>% 
  mutate(Other_Sites=paste(Site, collapse=","))

#>   Uniprot.ID Site              Other_Sites
#> 1     Q09666 E545 E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 2     Q09666 E550 E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 3     Q09666 E574 E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 4     Q09666 E766 E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 5     Q09666 E796 E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 6     Q8NE71 E403                E403,E705
#> 7     Q8NE71 E705                E403,E705
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

***Data:***

```r
df1 <-  read.table(text="Uniprot.ID Site
                         Q8NE71     E403     
                         Q8NE71     E705     
                         Q09666     E545     
                         Q09666     E550     
                         Q09666     E574     
                         Q09666     E766     
                         Q09666     E796 ", header=T)
```

---

#### *Update:*

***To address OP's follow-up comments about empty `Site` entries.***

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Uniprot.ID) %>% 
  mutate(Other_Sites=paste(unique(Site), collapse=",")) %>%
  mutate(Other_Sites=gsub("^,*|(?<=,),|,*$", "", 
                          str_remove_all(Other_Sites, if_else(Site==""," ", Site)),
                          perl=T))

#>    Uniprot.ID Site              Other_Sites
#> 1      Q8NE71 E403                     E705
#> 2      Q8NE71 E705                     E403
#> 3      Q09666 E545      E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 4      Q09666 E550      E545,E574,E766,E796
#> 5      Q09666 E574      E545,E550,E766,E796
#> 6      Q09666 E766      E545,E550,E574,E796
#> 7      Q09666 E796      E545,E550,E574,E766
#> 8      Q09666      E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 9      Q09666 E796      E545,E550,E574,E766
#> 10     Q09666      E545,E550,E574,E766,E796
#> 11     Q10B12
```

<sup>Created on 2019-06-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

***Example Data:***

```r
df1 <- structure(list(Uniprot.ID = c("Q8NE71", "Q8NE71", "Q09666", "Q09666", 
                                     "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q09666",
                                     "Q09666", "Q09666", "Q10B12"), 
                      Site = c("E403", "E705", "E545", "E550", "E574", "E766",
                               "E796", "", "E796", "", "")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -11L), class = "data.frame")

df1
#>    Uniprot.ID Site
#> 1      Q8NE71 E403
#> 2      Q8NE71 E705
#> 3      Q09666 E545
#> 4      Q09666 E550
#> 5      Q09666 E574
#> 6      Q09666 E766
#> 7      Q09666 E796
#> 8      Q09666     
#> 9      Q09666 E796
#> 10     Q09666     
#> 11     Q10B12
```

Comment: A question about this: could you suggest a way to ignore blank sites, as is, if the site is empty there will just be a bunch of commas in the Other_Sites column, additionally, is there a way to incorporate the Unique() function to remove duplicates in the Other_Sites column.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this that retains rows with no sites, and gives an empty cell for the Other_Sites?

Comment: Since your original code gives me almost exactly what I want I was thinking of somehow applying unique function afterwards to the Other_Sites column which would remove all the excess commas and duplicate sites

Comment: @CalvinBarber Look at the updates. Not the cleanest solution, but it works. If you want to keep the `Site` for the row itself (like my first solution) You need to replace ```str_remove_all(Other_Sites, if_else(Site==""," ", Site))``` with `Other_Sites`.

Comment: @M-M Is there a reason why you used `joins`? I am just trying to understand

Comment: @JasonMathews no particular reason. Instead of summarize I should've had mutate to not use join. Cheers. (Upvoted your answer)

Answer (score 1):

I didn't quite understand why `joins` are required in the accepted answer when it can be done just by using `setdiff` and `paste`

### Input

```
df1 <-  read.table(text="Uniprot.ID Site
                         Q8NE71     E403     
                         Q8NE71     E705     
                         Q09666     E545     
                         Q09666     E550     
                         Q09666     E574     
                         Q09666     E766     
                         Q09666     E796 ", header=T)
```

### Code

```
df1 %>% group_by(Uniprot.ID) %>%
  mutate(Other_Sites = paste(Site, collapse = ",")) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Other_Sites = paste(setdiff(unlist(strsplit(Other_Sites,",")), Site), collapse = ","))
```

### OutPut:

```
Uniprot.ID Site  Other_Sites        
  <fct>      <fct> <chr>              
1 Q8NE71     E403  E705               
2 Q8NE71     E705  E403               
3 Q09666     E545  E550,E574,E766,E796
4 Q09666     E550  E545,E574,E766,E796
5 Q09666     E574  E545,E550,E766,E796
6 Q09666     E766  E545,E550,E574,E796
7 Q09666     E796  E545,E550,E574,E766
```